# Google+ Login con Ionic 4 No muestra el View para seleccionar cuenta

Tags: angular7, ionic4, google+

Quiero implementar el login en mi aplicación con Google en Ionic, estoy usando el plugin de Google+, hice un ejemplo hace unos meses y me funciono correctamente, ahora lo quise implementar en otro proyecto y no me funciona, lei que degradando los paquetes a la versión que me funciono lo solucionaría pero al hacer esto me da errores de compilación con el gradle así que me toco volver a la versión por defecto del plugin de cordova pero no funciona, ejecuta la función login y no me muestra la pantalla para seleccionar cuenta, ni nada, no da errores en consola y eso no me ayuda a detectar que pueda estar pasando.

Si alguien pudo solucionarlo o le sucedio algo similar y lo puede compartir alguna alternativa, ya que trate de usar el login con google mediante la web con oAuth pero me sale error cuando se abre el webview y noce que mas alternativas hacer

Comment: Hola @StalinMaza, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Pase varios dias buscandole una solución al problema y finalmente me di cuenta que el problema era los servicios de Google, ya que en el proyecto usaba la versión 16 para el plugin Location Accuracy y la versión 11.8.0 para el plugin de Google Plus, y leyendo me decían que debe ser el mismo ya que si no da errores, en mi caso no me salia ningún error pero cambie eso, elimine las plataformas y los plugins y ejecute el comando "ionic cordova build android" y funciono  correctamente. Si alguien le sucede algo similar puede probar hacer lo que hice yo